# Why doesn't this lexical variable retain its value after the loop?

Tags: perl

Here is my Perl code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @words = ("alpha", "bravo", "charlie");

(my $word = $_) foreach @words;

print $word;
```

I would expect this code to do one of two things:

1. Print the string "charlie", which is the final value of `$word` after the loop is complete.
2. Complain of a compilation error, since `my $word` is a lexical variable whose scope is the `foreach` loop; it does not exist at the final line.

Instead, it seems the value of `$word` is `undef`, and Perl raises a warning and prints the empty string.

Why?

Comment: I'm a little surprised that `warnings` or `strict` aren't complaining, because to me that looks like variable that's no longer in scope.

Answer (score 6):

From [`perldoc perlsyn`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers)

> **NOTE**: The behaviour of a my, state, or our modified with a statement modifier conditional or loop construct (for example, my $x if ... ) is **undefined**. The value of the my variable may be undef, any previously assigned value, or possibly anything else. Don't rely on it. Future versions of perl might do something different from the version of perl you try it out on. Here be dragons.

Comment: But *why*? Why does Perl not simply declare that `EXPRESSION foreach LIST` is exactly syntactically equivalent to `foreach (LIST) { EXPRESSION }`? Wouldn't that be infinitely simpler and more predictable?

Comment: Because it's not exactly equivalent. The version using the statement modifier doesn't create a new lexical scope, and thus runs measurably faster. (And because it doesn't create a new lexical scope, this also means that a lexical variable can't be scoped to just that statement.)

Comment: @tobyink: so why isn't its value "charlie" afterwards? How is setting its value back to `undef` faster?

Comment: It's not so much that the variable gets set back to `undef`, but that it points to a different SV structure outside the loop. This is kind of related to how you can declare two variables with the same name in the same lexical scope, and the later one masks the earlier one, making it no longer available (unless you took a reference to it).